# vue reactivity in list with slot scoped component

Tags: vue.js

Good afternoon!
I have a loop and inside each element I display a separate component that takes props and gives them through the slot. I can't figure out why when new elements are added the update hooks happen on the old ones?

Example: 
have: 1 2 3 
add: 4 
log: created 4, updated 3, updated 2, updated 1 
Why is this happening?

```js
Vue.component('slot-component', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  created() {
    console.log('created', this._uid);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated', this._uid);
  },
  render(h) {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default(this.$attrs);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {      
      this.list.push({ 
        title: 'some'
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <div 
      v-for="(item, n) in list" 
      :key="n" 
      class="list-item"
    >
      <slot-component
        :title="item.title" 
        v-slot="props"
      >
        {{ props.title }}
      </slot-component>  
    </div>
    <button @click="add">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Thanks to **Raphael Rollet**  for clarifying that all array elements are updated when the array is changed globally. But then it is not entirely clear why this behavior behaves differently with a component that uses props

**Pass and use props — not call updated**

```js
Vue.component('slot-component', {
  props: ['title'],
  created() {
    console.log('created', this._uid);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated', this._uid);
  },
  template: `<div>{{ title }}</div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {  
      this.list.push({ title: 'some' });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <slot-component
      v-for="(item, n) in list" 
      :key="n" 
      :title="item.title"
      class="list-item"
    > 
    </slot-component>  
    <button @click="add">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pass and use props with slot — call updated**

```js
Vue.component('slot-component', {
  props: ['title'],
  created() {
    console.log('created', this._uid);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated', this._uid);
  },
  template: `<div><slot>{{ title }}</slot></div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {  
      this.list.push({ title: 'some' });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <slot-component
      v-for="(item, n) in list" 
      :key="n" 
      :title="item.title"
      class="list-item"
    > 
      {{ item.title }}
    </slot-component>  
    <button @click="add">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use $attrs — call updated**

```js
Vue.component('slot-component', {
  created() {
    console.log('created', this._uid);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated', this._uid);
  },
  template: `<div>{{ $attrs.title }}</div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {  
      this.list.push({ title: 'some' });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <slot-component
      v-for="(item, n) in list" 
      :key="n" 
      :title="item.title"
      class="list-item"
    > 
    </slot-component>  
    <button @click="add">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use slot — call updated**

```js
Vue.component('slot-component', {
  created() {
    console.log('created', this._uid);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated', this._uid);
  },
  template: `<div><slot></slot></div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {  
      this.list.push({ title: 'some' });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <slot-component
      v-for="(item, n) in list" 
      :key="n" 
      :title="item.title"
      class="list-item"
    > 
      <template #default></template>
    </slot-component>  
    <button @click="add">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour who seems "weird" all time because vue binding.

Your array is update so all property inside is update too, someone can have a nice explanation on that because it's too deep for me.

But the solution is to not use a update function on your child (if you don't want update something on every child), but set a watcher on what you want and do something in that case.

Like if you update a title on a child you do that:

```js
watch: {
  title(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

**Update:**

For the two last example in your update section, like i explain for me it's expected, it's seems weird yes, but it's binding with vue.

About the first, you use a props so you pass a string in your component and nothing else. He have no reason to update.

For the second you do the same thing but with a slot, the only explanation for me it's, when you initialise a slot (even empty) the slot access to the parent data, and because binding is update.

I found this:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#render-scope

> Slot content has access to the data scope of the parent component,
> because it is defined in the parent.

Be honest it's assumption, if anyone have a other explanation i want to know it !

Comment: If use a template instead of slots and without $attrs, then there will be no update. props: ['title'], template: '<div>{{ title }}</div>' => not update hook when adding new element. update hook call if $attrs in template/render fn or if render fn call $scopedSlots. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have an example about that? not sur i understand

Comment: update question